# Storing template language in database and have it rendered django

Tags: django, templates

I am using a template to email plugin (django-templated-mail) and am passing the email content to the template from the database via context such as :

```
{{ context.emailtitle }}
{{ context.main_text }}
```

I want to include other field tags in the main_text database entry so that i can for instance place the a users name in the email

```
Your name is {{ user.name }}
```

Is there a way I can include another field name in the database text so that it is rendered, or am I thinking about this wrong?

I have tried the above way and the output is "Your name is {{ user.name }}" rather than "Your name is John"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct mapping, but nothing avoids you from *rendering* this template text. For example:

```py
from django.template import Template, Context

template_text = 'Your name is {{ user.name }}'
user = Users.objects.first()  # we pick some user for demo purposes
template = Template(template_text)
ctx = Context({'user': user})
result = template.render(ctx)  # result is 'Your name is Cam'
```

We thus can do the rendering process here ourselves, and thus communicate the rendered output to some tool, response, etc.

This is more or less what happens if you perform a `render_to_response` call: you load the template text from the file, then you render the template with a context and request, and the output is wrapped in a HTTP response.